# R, fct_collapse to group values

Tags: r, forcats

I have imd scores (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) and want to group by 1-3, 4-6 and 7-10, without much success.  Continues to cause numerous errors, whatever I have attempted.
Sample error - Warning: Unknown levels in `f`: 1-3, 4-6, 7-10

Sample of the data.

```
imd
<chr>
5               
6               
1               
7               
6               
6               
1               
6               
2               
1
```

```
data_for_model %>%
 mutate(imd = fct_collapse(imd,
                     a = c('1:3'),
                     b = c('4:6'),
                     c = c('7:10'))) %>%
  group_by(imd) %>%
  summarise(Q1 = quantile(yes, .25),
            median = median(yes),
            Q3 = quantile(yes, .75),
            n = n())
```

Comment: since it's a character vector, you'll have to do `a = c("1", "2", "3"), b = c("4", "5", "6"), ` etc...

Comment: Thank you Phil, that seems to have done the trick. Many thanks.